# What is the frequency for each level of categorical variables to obtain the most reliable results?

Tags: statistical-significance, categorical-data

I'm working with a real dataset. In some variables, the frequency between each of the variables is not uniform. For example, in the Occup variable, the frequency for levels 2, 3, and 6 is very small. Also, for the PregHyp variable, the frequency at level 1 is too low.

```
[1] "Occup"
levels    1    2   3  4    5   6 
Frequency 57   3   5 696  41   1 

[1] "PregHyp"
levels     1   2 
 Frequency 9 631
```

What is the frequency for each level of categorical variables to obtain the most reliable results? I need a reference for this problem such as a book or article.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you wanna use a chi-square test for testing independencg of data, there are several limitation you should consider. One of which asked for is about the frequencies. In several context you need to have frequencies above 5 at least in 80% of cells. 
Here is a sample article
https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3900058/